# When using TActionlist ShowShareSheetAction1 is it possible to pass parameters to the shared app?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, android-sharing

When using TActionlist.ShowShareSheetAction1 is it possible to pass parameters to the shared app, such as email parameters: To whom you are sending the email "myname@gmail.com" and subject?

Comment: There is no `TActionlist.ShowShareSheetAction1`

Comment: What I meant is on Action list, adding a new Action class from Media Library: TShowShareSheetAction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't. It's not supported by this action